# join two tables to get custom result

Tags: mysql

I have two database tables : users and memberships

users structure
**Id   ,  User_Name  ,   Address**

memberships structure
**Id   ,  Start_date  ,  end_date   ,  user_id**

now I want to get users names that has no membership yet , and users with expired memberships

- note : the relation between them is one(user) to many(memberships)

I tried to join the two tables with this query

```
select users.*, memberships.*, users.id as member_id 
from users 
left outer join memberships 
on memberships.user_id = users.id 
where memberships.user_id is null 
or (memberships.end_date - curdate()) < 0
```

but I failed

please help :)

Comment: oh ,, sorry
select users.*(star) , memberships.*(star)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corrctly, you want all users that do not have a currently active membership:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from memberships m
                  where m.user_id = u.id and
                        current_date between m.start_date and m.end_date
                 );
```

You can also phrase this as a `left join`:

```
select u.*
from users u left outer join
     memberships m
     on m.user_id = m.id and
       current_date between m.start_date and m.end_date
where m.user_id is null;
```

The key idea here is to put the date comparison in the `on` clause.